# How to re render the component without using any API call in React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

[image]

From my above image, I've 2 views which can be changed when brown or green button is pressed. So when the brown button is selected already by default, the Map has a Marker in it. And when I press the green button, I want the Map's marker's to be removed.

So what I tried is to set a Asynchronous variable when the green button is pressed and get that Asynchronous variable in Map component.

And with that Asynchronous variable in Map component, I'll let the Map know to hide the Marker. But the problem is how can I re render my Map Component?

**Updated Question**

Dan's solution worked for me. But now I have a small problem in it. When I use `this.setState` like below in `componentWillMount` it gives me a warning. Then what other alternative can I use to show/hide my markers based on the value of props I'm receiving?

```
if(this.props.isMarkerVisible) {
        this.setState({ showDots: true })
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ showDots: false })
    }

         { this.state.showDots === true &&
                <Marker
                    ref={(mark) => { this.marker = mark; }}
                    coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
                    pinColor={colors.primaryColor}
                    image={require('../../../../assets/circle.png')}
                />
            }  

            { this.state.showDots === false &&  null }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Map` component will re-render when its props and state changes

Add a state variable to your parent component

```
this.state = {
  isMarkerVisible: false // Set this to your default value
}
```

Now, add a function which will set the state variable

```
onPress = isMarkerVisible => {
  this.setState({ 
    isMarkerVisible
  });
}
```

And finally, modify your `onPress` event on your buttons

```
// Green
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.onPress(false)}
/>

// Brown
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.onPress(true)}
/>
```

Modify your `Map` component so that it accepts a `isMarkerVisible` prop, the value of which is `this.state.isMarkerVisible`

```
<Map
  ...props
  isMarkerVisible={this.state.isMarkerVisible}
/>
```

Now inside of your `Map` component, you need to modify the rendering logic, here's some pseudo code below. You haven't added any `Map` code so I can't help with specifics.

```
If this.props.isMarkerVisible
Then render the marker
Else do not render the marker
```

**Update to reflect question**

You can do the following in your `Map` component. You do not need to modify state, just use the prop which is being passed in.

```
renderMarker = (coordinates) => {
  const { isMarkerVisible } = this.props;
  if(!isMarkerVisible) return null;
  return (
    <Marker
      ref={(mark) => { this.marker = mark; }}
      coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }}
      pinColor={colors.primaryColor}
      image={require('../../../../assets/circle.png')}
    />
  )
}


render() {
  const coordinates = { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 }
  return (
    <View>
      { this.renderMarker(coordinates) }
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Updated @ShubhamBisht

Comment: unfortunately for some reason I'm not able to use renderMarker function outside the render. It seems to be some coordinate issue. Isn't there any other way to do use setState inside `componentWillMount`? Maybe using `this._isMounted` ?

Comment: Can you share your render method in the question?

Comment: Answer updated so that the renderMarker function accepts coordinates